# Neat way to inizialize array of a base class with addresses of newly constructed derived objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to initialize an array of pointers to a base class through an initializer list, giving it addresses of objects of derived classes.

```
King king{square};
Queen queen{square};
Rook rook{square};

Piece* pieces[] = {&king, &queen, &rook};
```

Ideally, I'd like having

```
Piece* pieces[] = {
    &King{square},
    &Queen{square},
    &Rook{square}
};
```

But I can't use addresses of temporary objects.

Is there a neat way to write the constructors directly inside the initializer list?

Answer (score 2):

consider using [`new`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) operator that returns a pointer to the heap allocated object, so your object is no-longer a temporary value.

```cpp
Piece* pieces[] = {
    new King{square},
    new Queen{square},
    new Rook{square}
};
```

but you have to call [`delete`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete/) on every item in the array before the array is deleted so you won't have a memory leak.

instead i'd recommend using [shared pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) (or unique pointers), and make your array an array of shared pointers, and use [make shared](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/) instead of `new`, so you don't have to worry about memory leaks.

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Piece> pieces[] = {
    std::make_shared<King>(square),
    std::make_shared<Queen>(square),
    std::make_shared<Rook>(square)
};
```